# Error using XAdES4j to produce a detached signature with a xpath transform

Tags: xpath, digital-signature, xades4j, xml-dsig

I'm using the xades4j for produce xades signatures.
I want to include a xpath transform in a reference. My problem is the fact that it is a detached signature and the xpath has namespaces...

I tried with the following xml (an excerpt):

```
<collection xmlns:t="http://test.xades4j/tracks" Id="root">
    <album>
        <title>Questions, unanswered</title>
        <artist>Steve and the flubberblubs</artist>
        <year>1989</year>
        <t:tracks xmlns:t="http://test.xades4j/tracks">
            <t:song length="4:05" tracknumber="1">
                <t:title>What do you know?</t:title>
                <t:artist>Steve and the flubberblubs</t:artist>
                <t:lastplayed>2006-10-17-08:31</t:lastplayed>
            </t:song>
            <t:song length="3:45" tracknumber="2">
                <t:title>Who do you know?</t:title>
                <t:artist>Steve and the flubberblubs</t:artist>
                <t:lastplayed>2006-10-17-08:35</t:lastplayed>
            </t:song>
```

If I try to do an enveloped signature of this document, with the code:

```
String xpathString = "/collection/album/t:tracks/t:song[ @tracknumber = 1 ]";

DataObjectDesc obj1 = new DataObjectReference("");
obj1.withTransform(new EnvelopedSignatureTransform());
obj1.withTransform(XPath2Filter.intersect( xpathString ));

SignedDataObjects objs = new SignedDataObjects( obj1 );         
Document doc = getDocument(path+fileName);

signer.sign( objs, doc.getDocumentElement() );
```

It works fine and reference looks like this:

```
<ds:Reference Id="xmldsig-44c42d30-9a42-4290-afba-b89dc807a668-ref0" URI="">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2">
                        <dsig-xpath:XPath xmlns:dsig-xpath="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2" Filter="intersect">/collection/album/t:tracks/t:song[ @tracknumber = 1 ]</dsig-xpath:XPath>
                    </ds:Transform>
                </ds:Transforms>
```

BUT, if I try the detached version, with the code:

```
String xpathString = "/collection/album/t:tracks/t:song[ @tracknumber = 1 ]";

DataObjectDesc obj1 = new DataObjectReference( fileName );
obj1.withTransform(XPath2Filter.intersect( xpathString ));

SignedDataObjects objs = new SignedDataObjects( obj1 );
objs.withBaseUri( "file:///"+path );

signer.sign( objs, db.newDocument());
```

I get the error: Prefix must resolve to a namespace: t

My problem is similar to the one described here: [namespace and xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873058/namespace-and-xpath)
But there are no answers and what I have is a little different. I guest that an answer to that problem may help me...

So, how can I set the namespace to a transform in xades4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice catch! Currently there's no way to specify this. However, I think the underlying Apache Santuario API supports this using the [setXPathNamespaceContext](http://santuario.apache.org/Java/api/org/apache/xml/security/utils/ElementProxy.html#setXPathNamespaceContext(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method. Looks like the output `XPath` element will contain the namespace declarations. I'll test this and add support if it's possible.

Comment: Yes, I looked around to see where I could set the setXPathNamespaceContext. I saw an example where the xpath element had the namespace: <dsig-xpath:XPath xmlns:dsig-xpath="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2" xmlns:t="http://test.xades4j/tracks" Filter="intersect">

Comment: Support for namespaces on XPath queries has been added.